# App not functioning from Play store, but is fine when run from Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play

I deployed my first Flutter app a few days ago. I was pretty disappointed to see that when I downloaded it from the Google Play store, it would just perpetually load the weather information I'm getting from an API.

When I run the app from Android Studio, it works perfectly. When I download it from the store, I'm stuck on the loading screen which usually takes less than a second on WiFi. Why is this? The app starts by asking me for the local location which is great, it should then make an API call then display the home screen but it doesn't.

I had a look through the android manifests and was quite confused. I have a Debug, Main and Profile manifest. Debug and Profile manifests are tiny, only requesting Internet permissions, whereas the Main has all the usual info, where the only permission called for is Coarse Location, no internet.

Could someone point me in the right direction? I feel like I have to add the Internet permission to the Main manifest now, despite not thinking I really need it as my app has been functioning fine without it. I just don't want to add one line of code, build a new APK, wait for that to roll out to the app store then download it again to see any changes, I'm sure there's a better way of doing this test but I don't know it.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add Internet permission to your main manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced  same issue in my app because I forgot to get internet
permission
in main manifest file

You need to add Internet permission to your main manifest

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have build a appbundle for the Google Play upload follow [this guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#offline-using-the-bundle-tool) for a better understanding of how to test the appbundle offline before deploying it again and again to the google play store.

Otherwise when you have built an apk for that simply follow [this guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#install-an-apk-on-a-device).

What you can also do is simply change the Build Type in Android Studio itself before you run the app from Android Studio. Like described [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#how-do-i-build-a-release-from-within-android-studio).

On this side you can also find further information about R8 or proguard if you are interested in that.